# How to limit keybinds to normal mode and not to override keybinds in minibuffer?

Tags: key-bindings, evil

I've keybinded `&é"'...` to selecting windows:

```
  (global-set-key (kbd "²") 'select-window-0)
  (global-set-key (kbd "&") 'select-window-1)
  (global-set-key (kbd "é") 'select-window-2)
  (global-set-key (kbd "\"") 'select-window-3)
  (global-set-key (kbd "\'") 'select-window-4)
  (global-set-key (kbd "(") 'select-window-5)
  (global-set-key (kbd "-") 'select-window-6)
  (global-set-key (kbd "è") 'select-window-7)
  (global-set-key (kbd "_") 'select-window-8)
  (global-set-key (kbd "ç") 'select-window-9)
```

However now everytime I need to type something in the minibuffer that contains those characters it tries to select those windows instead. How would I limit the scope of these keybinds only to the normal mode in buffers that are not the minibuffer ? Also when I'm in insert mode I would like those keybinds to just insert the characters.

Answer (score 1):

I'm just assuming that you are using Evil and have edited the tags accordingly.

If you don't want to globally change  key, you will need to use `define-key` with the right keymap.  This introduces one more difficulty, the keymap must be defined when running your code:

```
(with-eval-after-load 'evil
  (define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "²") 'select-window-0)
  (define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "&") 'select-window-1)
  (define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "é") 'select-window-2)
  (define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "\"") 'select-window-3)
  (define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "\'") 'select-window-4)
  (define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "(") 'select-window-5)
  (define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "-") 'select-window-6)
  (define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "è") 'select-window-7)
  (define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "_") 'select-window-8)
  (define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "ç") 'select-window-9))
```

In the absence of `with-eval-after-load`, use `(eval-after-load 'evil '(progn ...))`.